# SQL - Percentiles

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table:

```
country(ID, city, freg, counts, date)
```

I want to calculate the 90th percentile of counts in a specific interval of dates ($min and $max).

I've already did the same but with the average (code below):

```
SELECT
      AVG(counts)
FROM country
WHERE date>= @min AND date < @max
      ;
```

How can I calculate the 90th percentile instead of the average?

Comment: What mean `with the attributes in brackets` ?? What formula you use for  90th percentil?

Comment: Is it `ctdivol` or `ctdivol_mGy`?

Comment: ctdivol_mGy @GigiSan . It was a mistake, sorry. Have already edit.

Comment: What is your desire output. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 2):

Finally, something GROUP_CONCAT is good for...

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                GROUP_CONCAT(ct.ctdivol ORDER BY ct.ctdivol SEPARATOR ','),',',90/100 * COUNT(*) + 1
                         ),',',-1
                      ) `90th Percentile`
  FROM ct
  JOIN exam e
    ON e.examid = ct.examid
   AND e.date BETWEEN @min AND @max
 WHERE e.modality = 'ct';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Strawberry . I'm getting this error: 

#1054 - Unknown column 'ct.ctdivol' in 'field list'

Comment: @F.Rita Yeah, when you decide what your columns are actually called, let us know. Have fun.

Comment: @F.Rita so you just need to replace `ctdivol` with `ctdivol_mGy`

Comment: Yeah I've already did that, but I'm not sure if the result is the correct one.

Comment: @Strawberry if I want to calculate the 90th percentile between two dates and between two ctdivol_mGy values, how can I add the final condition to your query?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: When you do GROUP_CONCAT() you are concatenating ALL ctdivol_mGy values separated by a comma, but I want to concatenate the ctdivol values that are between two given values (@ctdivol_min and @ctdivol_max). I understand your point but I'm new in stackoverflow and didn't know that to ask a SQL question it is necessary all the steps you and other users mentioned. I'm sorry for that @Strawberry .

Answer (score 0):

It appears doing it with a single query is not possible. At least not in MySQL.

You can do it in multiple queries:

1) Select how many rows satisfy your condition.

```
SELECT
      COUNT(*)
FROM exam
INNER JOIN ct on exam.examID = ct.examID AND ct.ctdivol_mGy > 0
WHERE exam.modality = 'CT'
      AND exam.date >= @min AND exam.date < @max
```

2) Check the percentile threshold by multiplying the number of rows by percentile/100. For example:

```
Number of rows in previous count: 200
Percentile: 90%
Number of rows to threshold: 200 * (90/100) = 180
```

3) Repeat the query, order by the value you want the percentile from and `LIMIT` the result to the only row number you found in the 2nd point. Like so:

```
SELECT
      ct.ctdivol_mGy
FROM exam
INNER JOIN ct on exam.examID = ct.examID AND ct.ctdivol_mGy > 0
WHERE exam.modality = 'CT'
      AND exam.date >= @min AND exam.date < @max
ORDER BY ct.ctdivol_mGy
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 179 --> Take 1 row after 179 rows, so our 180th we need
```

You'll get the 180th value of the selected rows, so the 90th percentile you need.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like @Strawberry 's query does it in one hit. Didn't know about that! Cheers if it works!